# Set up Task Scheduler tasks under Local Account in Windows 10 - incorrect password

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, scheduled-tasks, task-scheduler

I have a PC running Windows 10. I used to use a local account to log on. The local account is a member of the local Administrators group. Recently I changed to use the Microsoft account authentication with local pin.

I can add a task in the Task scheduler without a problem if I select "Run only when the user is logged on." But when I select "run whether the user is logged on or not," I am prompted with a dialog box that asks me the password corresponding to the user account.

[image]

[image]

The default user account is still the local account (not the Microsoft account although I use the Microsoft account to log on). When I try to type the old password for the local user, it says something like below.

[image]

I am pretty sure my local password is correct. Now if I try to use the Microsoft Account instead, it gives me a different error.

[image]

I am not sure how I can add/edit tasks to Task scheduler if I am using Microsoft account to log on.

Answer (score 4):

I figured this out myself. In the above, although it displays the account name of my original local user name, I need to log on with my new Microsoft account password.

Comment: Thank you. A better solution would be for Microsoft not to have multiple entry points for accessing a single user account. But, it's unlikely they'll ever provide a secure OS.